# Conflicts between Apache POI PackagePart and XMLSlideShow

Tags: apache-poi

I am facing an issue with Apache POI, where I am using a template and modifying the components within, wondering if anyone else has faced a similar issue and knows how to work around it.

This is for an XMLSlideShow.

I am working with charts, so I am using a SAXReader and reading the file input as so...

```
        OPCPackage opcPackage = ppt.getPackage();
        PackagePartName chartPartName =
            PackagingURIHelper.createPartName(getChartName(i));
        PackagePart chartPart = opcPackage.getPart(chartPartName);

        SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
        org.dom4j.Document doc = reader.read(chartPart.getInputStream());
```

Note: The i in getChartName(i), it gets the package part for the specific chart I want, I am looping through and editing multiple charts (at most 8).

and then writing it

```
OutputStream os = chartPart.getOutputStream();
        os.write(doc.asXML().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        os.close();
```

In the past this has worked well for previous projects.

I also do something similar for the excel data in the powerpoint for the chart.

```
        PackagePartName chartPartName =
            PackagingURIHelper.createPartName(getEmbeddingName(i));
        PackagePart chartPart = opcPackage.getPart(chartPartName);
        XSSFWorkbook embeddedWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(chartPart.getInputStream());
```

However now I find when I try to open the powerpoint, the chart data is the same (only to refresh in microsoft once I open the excel sheet. The excel sheet is fine).

If I read the data inside each chartPart, the xml was correctly updated, however when I unzip the pptx and look at the chart xml, it has been unchanged.

Trying to figure out what's wrong, I tried making a new XMLSlideShow using the package parts to see if anything changes.

```
XMLSlideShow slideshow = new XMLSlideShow(ppt.getPackage());
```

If I ignore editing the excel data for the chart, the charts in the pptx are correctly updated and microsoft says no file is corrupted! However the reason I needed to ignore the excel data is because microsoft is saying the file is corrupted. Which is odd because previously the charts weren't updating but the excel data was and no corruption error was thrown.

Also, after making a new XMLSlideShow, the changes I made in the previous slideshow are gone.

What is the best way around this? For other projects, we did something similar and we weren't facing an issue, why is there an issue now? The only difference between this one and previous templates is that this has 8 charts on one slide, and the others had one chart per slide. How ever I am updating them one at a time.

Comment: "In the past this has worked well for previous projects.": What has changed? The used Apache POI version? If so, then which version had worked, which does not? Something else? What?

Comment: I doubt much programmers will do that like you do. I do the same but only using `XSLF` and `XDDF` from Apache POI and without overriding the XML of package parts directly. Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56633424/im-trying-to-change-the-values-of-a-line-graph-in-a-slide-but-it-is-not-working/56652364#56652364 - for a line chart, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66774234/java-edit-bar-chart-in-ppt-by-using-poi/66777798#66777798 - for a bar chart, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71079240/how-to-update-ext-list-value-of-pptx-scatter-chart/71112994#71112994 - a scatter chart.

Comment: We haven't changed the version of Apache POI or anything since we did the last templates. However I changed my approach using Apache POI only and not the SAXReader and things look much better.

Thank you! Always appreciate your help on these @AxelRichter, helped me a lot in the past.